# singing certificate or hash is not recognized -- notepad++ 7.7.1

Tags: notepad++

I am using notepad ++ 7.7.1.

While opening a Notepad++ in windows 10, I am getting this error "singing certificate or hash is not recognized"

Comment: it's not related to programming question.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3805

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to [7.3.3](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.3.3.html) and it works great.
Looks like 7.7.1 something was wrong.